# Azure documentdb stored procedure returning partial result

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Currently I have got given stored procedure

```
function getData() {     
  var context = getContext();
  var collection = context.getCollection();

  var output = collection.map(function (doc) {
      return {
          id: doc.id,
          name: doc.name,
          status: doc.status,
          description: doc.description,
          owner: doc.owner
      }
  })

  return JSON.stringify(output)
}
```

Issue here is that it only returs 7 documents (matching what you get when you not get 'load' action on azure panel) and is skipping rest of the collection.

I believe that it can be fixed with using SQL query syntaxt but I would like to know how can I query all documents in the collection without using it.

Comment: I see this a lot lately, but why do you `JSON.stringify()`. In my code, I simply return the output with no serialization. I'm wondering if there is some advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `FeedCallback` like shown [here](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/Collection.html#map) and make the signature of the callback be `function(error, resources, options)`. Look for errors. Also inspect the options parameter for a `continuation`. If that fails to give you enough information to fix the problem, then you might want to consider a more traditional query and transformation approach not using `collection.map()`.

Comment: Already got to that point. Error parameter in FeedCallback is throwing 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token u'. Any idea where it's coming from?

Comment: Nothing that I can think of. I suggest escalating to the DocumentDB team as a potential bug or switching to not using `collection.map()`. I think .map was added to support javascript native queries and it wouldn't surprise me if it was less well tested outside of a `collection.chain()`. Since you are not transforming values in your map function, you can duplicate that functionality just by specifying the fields you want in your SELECT clause. Note, you'll still have to deal with paging in the case of continuations.

Comment: Will do Larry. Been trying to test native javascript to query documents in collections but as you said it seems not to work as expected.